# How to introduce ASP.NET Web API into webform based legacy system running on .Net 3.5

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, communication

My scenario is described as below:

I have one legacy web app (webform based) running on .Net 3.5 and deployed on IIS 6.0. For some reason I really could not upgrade to .Net 4.0 or higher version.

Now, I want to provide RESTful API to third party. So I wanna introduce ASP.Net Web API. But, unfortunately, Web API can not run on .Net 3.5 environment. So, I plan to create a new web app providing web service and deploy it as a separate web app on the same IIS 6 server.

My question are: 
   1) Do I have better solution regarding this requirement? for example, can I use web api 1.1 or some other version to make it run under .Net 3.5 environment?

2) If there is no better solution, how does my Web API based app communicate with my existing app? Currently, I plan to use WCF.

```
Regarding my current solution, it is really tedious. Please kindly help me find a better solution. Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. ASP.NET Web API requires .NET 4.0 (initially)/.NET 4.5(now) and above. You could never bring it down to .NET 3.5. There was never an official version of Web API released by Microsoft for .NET 3.5.

Comment: Thanks, Lex. I will create a new Web API app running on .NET 4.5 and use WCF to communicate with my legacy system.